# Can I install os on Pi 400 without sd card reader?

Tags: pi-400

I've been having problems installing an OS onto my Raspberry Pi 400 as I don't have an SD card reader, I've seen previous posts along these lines but none of them specify if I can do this with a Raspberry Pi 400.

Comment: Are you referring to usb boot or network install? Both can be done on Pi400.

Comment: *"I don't have an SD card reader"* -> Unless you are living in Antarctica, USB adapters are easy to get for < $5, probably worth the expense...